# Google heat map change colour based on intensity

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, heatmap

I have crested a heat-map using google maps js api. all the locations are weighted and would like the color to represent the weights instead i am getting a red dot that fades to yellow and then green. not this is only a test and i will be populating the zip codes and weights from a database

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=visualization"></script>
```

.

```
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(40.785091,-73.968285),
    zoom:11,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

  codeAddress("10001", 6119);
  codeAddress("10002", 5180);
  codeAddress("10003", 4110);
  codeAddress("10004", 899);
  codeAddress("10005", 520);
  codeAddress("10006", 599);

   function codeAddress(zip, noAccidents) {
    //var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zip}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        var hotSpot = results[0].geometry.location;
        console.log(hotSpot + " " + noAccidents);

        var heatMapZip = [
        {location: hotSpot, weight: noAccidents}

        ];

       var color =[
            "#ff0000",
            "#00ff00"
        ];

        var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
          data: heatMapZip,
          radius: 50,
          dissapating: false
        });
        heatmap.setMap(map);

      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }


}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[image: MAP]

Comment: You're a little vague on how 'weight' corresponds to colours.  What does your array `color` do?  Nothing it seems... why not pass that as the `gradient` parameter for your HeatmapLayerOptions?  Also NB: the parameter is documented as `dissipating` not `dissapating`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the function `heatmap.set('gradient', gradient);` to set the color of your heat map. The color can be calculated by the # of accident, and the max and min of the # in your data set.

I created a fiddle for that, hope it helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/hzy0y6es/